# Calabash - Can't find Android SDK

Tags: android, calabash

I am using Calabash and the command Calabash-Android resign from the Windows Power Shell command line generates the following error: "Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed".  However I have the SDK installed as it was installed when I installed Android Studio and my ANDROID_HOME environment variableis set to C:\Users\user name here\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.  I have read all the similar stackoverflow questions and googled for possible solutions to no avail.  Please help!
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out so I am posting it here in case someone else runs into the same issue.  The problem is that Windows Powershell doesn't recognize changes to the environment variables that take place after Powershell is launched.  You must close the current Powershell window and open a new one in order for the changes to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only closing and opening again command line didn't help. I had to put **SDK** path in my windows path before ruby. Why? I don't know, but it worked that way. Maybe this could help someone else.